# In jni, is it possible for callee function argument of caller object to be a null value?

Tags: java, c, multithreading, java-native-interface

I'm programming Java application that makes JNI calls. It is multi-thread program.
Since I have made this program, I have never seen this situation. So I try to ask here. (Apologize for my bad Eng.)

*Shard.java*

```
private native LocalityGroupMap getGroupMap();
```

*GroupMap.h*

```
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_indep_jdbc_dt_Shard_getGroupMap
  (JNIEnv *, jobject )
```

I made `GroupMap.h` file from `Shard.java` file as above.
For ease of explanation, I deleted all arguments.

I thought the second argument of Java_getGroupMap function (`jobject`) was the object calling the function.
So I thought it can not be null value.

But, in multi thread program, SIGSEGV  occurred as follows:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fb83a2af220, pid=93582, tid=140424292456192
#
# JRE version: 6.0_43-b01
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.14-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x4f5220]  unsigned+0xd0
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007fb83426c000):  JavaThread "Thread-62" [_thread_in_vm, id=93866, stack(0x00007fb71401d000,0x00007fb71411e000)]

siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr=0x0000000000000000

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000000, RBX=0x00007fb83a8437b0, RCX=0x00007fb83a8437d0, RDX=0x00007fb83b3c2000
RSP=0x00007fb71411a880, RBP=0x00007fb71411a8e0, RSI=0x0000000000000c00, RDI=0x00007fb83a8583d0
R8 =0x0000000000000ffc, R9 =0x00007fb83a8583d8, R10=0x00007fb83a85c278, R11=0x00007fb83a545d10
R12=0x00007fb83426c1d0, R13=0x0000000000000000, R14=0x00007fb71411a880, R15=0x00007fb83426c000
RIP=0x00007fb83a2af220, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010246, CSGSFS=0x002b000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000004
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00007fb71411a880)



Instructions: (pc=0x00007fb83a2af220)
0x00007fb83a2af200:   45 a8 00 00 00 00 48 89 5d c0 48 89 5d a0 48 83
0x00007fb83a2af210:   7b 08 00 0f 85 37 01 00 00 48 8b 1d e8 ae 6d 00
0x00007fb83a2af220:   49 8b 55 00 80 3b 00 0f 84 13 01 00 00 4c 8b 1d
0x00007fb83a2af230:   a4 92 6d 00 8b 52 08 41 8b 4b 08 48 d3 e2 49 03 

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RBX=0x00007fb83a8437b0: <offset 0xa897b0> in /usr/share/jdk1.6.0_43/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so at 0x00007fb839dba000
RCX=0x00007fb83a8437d0: <offset 0xa897d0> in /usr/share/jdk1.6.0_43/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so at 0x00007fb839dba000
RDX=0x00007fb83b3c2000 is an unknown value
RSP=0x00007fb71411a880 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007fb83426c000
RBP=0x00007fb71411a8e0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007fb83426c000
RSI=0x0000000000000c00 is an unknown value
RDI=0x00007fb83a8583d0: <offset 0xa9e3d0> in /usr/share/jdk1.6.0_43/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so at 0x00007fb839dba000
R8 =0x0000000000000ffc is an unknown value
R9 =0x00007fb83a8583d8: <offset 0xa9e3d8> in /usr/share/jdk1.6.0_43/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so at 0x00007fb839dba000
R10=0x00007fb83a85c278: <offset 0xaa2278> in /usr/share/jdk1.6.0_43/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so at 0x00007fb839dba000
R11=0x00007fb83a545d10: <offset 0x78bd10> in /usr/share/jdk1.6.0_43/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so at 0x00007fb839dba000
R12=0x00007fb83426c1d0 is an unknown value
R13=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R14=0x00007fb71411a880 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007fb83426c000
R15=0x00007fb83426c000 is a thread


Stack: [0x00007fb71401d000,0x00007fb71411e000],  sp=0x00007fb71411a880,  free space=1014k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0x4f5220]  unsigned+0xd0
C  [libgoldilocksjnigc.so+0x587ea5]  ...+0x3e
C  [libgoldilocksjnigc.so+0x58baa6]  Java_indep_jdbc_dt_Shard_getGroupMap+0xd4
j  indep.jdbc.dt.Shard.getGroupMap(Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;Lindep/jdbc/dt/LocalityGroupMap;Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;ZBIILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Lindep/jdbc/dt/LocalityGroupMap;+0
j  indep.jdbc.dt.Shard.getShardGroupMap(Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;Z)Lindep/jdbc/dt/LocalityGroupMap;+122
...
...
j  MultiThread.AccountDeposit(Ljava/sql/Connection;JI)V+171
j  MultiThread.run()V+186
```

C file is below:

```
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_indep_jdbc_dt_Shard_getGroupMap(
    JNIEnv * aJni,
    jobject  aObj,
```

In core file, **aObj's value is null**. I wonder it is possible.

Comment: The second argument to your native function is **the object on which the method is invoked**. What does that call look like? From the stack it looks like it should be in `getShardGroupMap`

Comment: Post the complete code.